# PowerShell - Moving files from one server to the next when the filename changes

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I am trying to copy multiple files, which name changes from day to day, from one machine to the next and am having issues.  The names always starts with "Stock Status" and then ends with numbers.

I have tried the following code:

```
$strSourceFile = "C:\Test\[Stock]*"
$strTargetDir = "C$\Test\Test2"
$astrComputerList = ( "kburrows-xplt" )

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($strSourceFile)) 
{
    foreach ($strComputer in $astrComputerList) {
        $strTargetPath = "\\$strComputer\$strTargetDir"
        copy-item $strSourceFile -destination $strTargetPath
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that strSourceFile is set to a string, but I think it needs to be an expression so this would work.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Maybe I am going about it all wrong.

```
  Directory: C:\Test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                          
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                          
-a---         11/1/2013   3:09 AM    2954557 Stock Status Report88744.XML                                                                                                  
-a---         11/1/2013   3:25 AM     528934 Stock Status Report89386.XML                                                                                                  
-a---         11/1/2013   3:31 AM     103583 Stock Status Report89772.XML
```

Comment: Go easy on me.  This is my very first PowerShell Script.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend for this operation:

```
$strSourceFile = "C:\Test\"
$strTargetDir = "C$\Test\Test2"
$astrComputerList = ( "kburrows-xplt" )

Get-ChildItem $strSourceFile -Filter "Stock Status*" | foreach{
  if (Test-Path -Path $_.FullName -PathType Leaf) 
  {
    foreach ($strComputer in $astrComputerList) {
        $strTargetPath = "\\$strComputer\$strTargetDir"
        copy-item $_.FullName -destination $strTargetPath
    }
  }
}
```

$_ is the current object in the pipeline. Similar to "this" in other languages. The `-Filter` allows you trim down the results as needed. I believe `-Include` and `-Exclude` allow you to filter based on extension as well if that helps.

I as well don't have 1.0 available so I can't fully test.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the square brackets around Stock in your first line. You can use wildcards in a string as part of Copy-Item.

Also, you can replace

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists($strSourceFile)
```

with

```
Test-File $strSourceFile
```

I just noticed that you tagged this as PowerShell 1.0, so perhaps the wildcard doesn't work with Copy-Item on that version. In that case, try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $strSourceFile | Copy-Item -Destination $strTargetPath
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a system with PowerShell 1.0 handy to test this with.

Comment: I have done exactly as you have said, but it still does not copy the files over

Comment: Try running the command "Get-ChildItem $strSourceFile". It should help give you better visibility into which files are being selected.

Comment: Ok, this is what returned:

Comment: Sry... I posted what returned above, so that it would show properly

Comment: I just updated my answer with another possible solution. I hadn't noticed that you have the question tagged as PowerShell 1.0.